# MySQL weird ordering requirement

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a MySQL query like so:

```
SELECT
id,
CASE
WHEN (cond1) THEN 1
WHEN (cond2) THEN 2
WHEN (cond3) THEN 3
END `rank`
FROM `table`
```

Is there a way to order it so that the result I get will have an alternating order of:

```
rank
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

The order of the 1s, 2s and 3s doesn't matter as long as they follow the pattern 123123[...]. It can be the order they were entered into the database or random.

I have a database which consists of three types of items and they can be repeatable.

```
rock      1
paper     2
scissors  3
rock      1
rock      1
rock      1
scissors  3
paper     2
```

What i want to do is order them rock, paper, scissors, rock, papers, scissors for as long as it can reach.

I'm doing this because a majority of my data (> 90%) is scissors and when I'm displaying my data with pagination, the first page (LIMIT 0, N) is all scissors. Even ORDER BY RAND() wouldn't help because of this majority so this is why.

Comment: ahhh!!! your question is not clear.. what are u trying to do

Comment: How do you choose which `order` 1 comes before another 1? Your question is not complete! Please, give us some other detail.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? - HIGH LEVEL. Need more info

Answer (score 2):

Modification from a similar question's answer in Stackoverflow:

```
SELECT name, cond
FROM (
   SELECT name, cond, @a := @a+1 AS inc 
       FROM table, ( select @a := 0 ) as SqlVars 
       WHERE cond = 1
   UNION
   SELECT name, cond, @b := @b+1 AS inc 
       FROM table, ( select @b := 0 ) as SqlVars 
       WHERE cond = 2
   UNION
   SELECT name, cond, @c := @c+1 AS inc 
       FROM table, ( select @c := 0 ) as SqlVars 
       WHERE cond = 3
)
ORDER BY inc
```

It's limited to finite small number of conditions. If the conditions are not fixed limited small then you should go with procedure. And it is not an optimal query either.

Another approach is to add a new field in the database and take care of inserting a goog value there (MAX of the same condition + 1) so that use that column for ordering.

Comment: Very Slick Query and will probably perfectly hit, however, you don't have any declaration of you SQL variables for @a, @b, @c... I've never tried without first an explicit declaration of them such as...  (select @a := 0) as SQLVars   in the query as an "alias" reference just so they are created.

Comment: Totally agree with you. A good programming practice must be to declare them first. And even better to place it in a procedure. I also mentioned the drawback that it would be slow query. The best approach will be to keep a an extra field in the table as I already mentioned. It will be then declared as Index and the select query will be very simple and fast.

Comment: I edited your answer and put in the SQL Vars declarations (in-line), hope your not offended.

Answer (score 0):

How about using modulus?

```
SELECT id, (((id - 1) % 3) + 1 ) FROM [...]
```

If your id starts at 1, and goes up without interruption, the second column will go 1,2,3,1,2,3.

If you select from a [MySQL row generator](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2011-07-30/mysql-row-generator#mysql_generator_code), and do an inner join on your original table on rank, you can probably make it work this way.